# Pandas get random values from two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'audio': ['audio1', 'audio2', 'audio3'],
    'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'col2': ['D', 'E', 'F']
})
```

I need to get value of column "audio" and value from column col1 or col2 randomly for eaсh row like this:

```
audio  value (value is random value from col1 or col2)
audio1 A
audio2 E
audio3 C
```

Comment: Sorry, i explained it bad. i mean random value for each row, not for full columns, for example: A B F, A E C, D B C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `numpy` based approach:

```
v = df[['col1', 'col2']].values
ix = np.random.randint(0,v.shape[1],df.shape[0])
df['value'] = np.take_along_axis(v, ix[:,None], 1)
```

---

```
print(df)

    audio  col1 col2 value
0  audio1    A    D     D
1  audio2    B    E     E
2  audio3    C    F     C
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try sample with `axis=1`:

```
df.set_index('audio').sample(n=1,axis=1)
#df.set_index('audio').apply(np.random.choice,axis=1) #for random values in each row
```

Example:

```
i=1
while i < 6:
    print(df.set_index('audio').sample(n=1,axis=1),'\n')
    i += 1
```

---

```
        col2
audio      
audio1    D
audio2    E
audio3    F 

       col2
audio      
audio1    D
audio2    E
audio3    F 

       col1
audio      
audio1    A
audio2    B
audio3    C 

       col1
audio      
audio1    A
audio2    B
audio3    C 

       col2
audio      
audio1    D
audio2    E
audio3    F
```